# Internal storage reading writing

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-download-manager

setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this, "/download", "app-debug.apk"); why this save in internal storage?

and why Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.example.xxx/files/download/app-debug.apk

```
 downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://");
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this, "/download", "app-debug.apk");
request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
Long reference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

File imagePath = new File(getFilesDir(), "download");
File newFile = new File(imagePath, "app-debug.apk");
CharSequence text1 = "no file";
Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), newFile.getAbsolutePath()+"can't find file ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

if(!newFile.exists()){toast1.show(); return false;}
Uri uri2 = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,"com.example.xxx",newFile);
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.setData(uri2);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
i.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(i);
```

provider paths

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!--<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>-->
<files-path
 name="tlumacz1"
path="download"/>
</paths>
```

manifest

```
 <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.xxx"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

mby there is external storage in internal storage or sth like this?

Comment: Add following code: `if(!newFile.exists()){Toast( ... file does not exist .. ); return;}`. Please report.

Comment: For getFilesDir() you need to specify an <internal-path. Maybe its called <files-path. See the docs.

Comment: I tried this dont work

Comment: It is unclear what you tried. That does always work. No reason it would fail. Show complete code. Did you add the code i proposed? You should have reacted on my suggestion of course.

Comment: i want to get in Android/data/com.app/files/download/file.apk by fileprovider how can i do this ? File which i want to open i save with setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this, "/download", "app-debug.apk");

Comment: `Android/data/com.app/files/`. That is not a path on an Android device to begin with. Where did you see it? Now add the code i proposed and report!

Comment: <files-path it's for it. i applied your code and it returns that toast (file don't exist )

Comment: Please add that code to your post. And show complete xml.

Comment: `i save with setDestinationInExternalFilesDir()`. Then why are you using getFilesDir() to retrieve the file? It will not be there for shure. Well as you saw.

Comment: so what should i use ?

Comment: You have not added the proposed code to your post. This does not make fun.

Comment: you were talking about this ?

Comment: So if the file is not there the user of your app only sees "no file". That is not very informative. Moreover you use three codelines for a Toast. Do it in one and tell the user which file. `newFile.getAbsolutePath()` is the name of the file.

Comment: It returns data/user/0/com.example.xxx/files/download/app-debug.apk
it's for sure not path of my file :/  but i don't know which path is for my file ...

Comment: I wait until you updated your code with a good Toast. You realise that my first comment where i asked you to add that code is seven hours back? Inform the user in a proper way!

Comment: `returns data/user/0/com.example.xxx/files/download/app-debug.apk`. No. It returns `/data/user/0/com.example.xxx/files/download/app-debug.apk`.

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: `"can't find file "`. Tell the user of your app which file. Tell him complete path. Its eight hours ago now.

Comment: Yea now he knows which file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `getFilesDir()` by `getExternalFilesDir()`.

And adapt provider paths. Like you originally had.

Comment: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.xxx/files/download/app-debug.apk

'<external-path
        name="tlumacz1"
        path="download"/>
</paths>'
I made it like : getExternalFilesDir(null) because there was needed sth in ()
It crashed without toast :o

Comment: That should be `path="."`

Comment: so now ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive flg=0x10000001 }

Comment: Use setDataAndType() instead. Remove the flags.